# How to remove decimal number intext file using bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

Having text file like this

```
172.16.0.30,42056.0
172.16.0.30,42058.0
172.16.0.30,42060.0
```

I want to remove decimal number of port to output like

```
172.16.0.30,42056
172.16.0.30,42058
172.16.0.30,42060
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you really limited to `bash`? This would be as simple `sed 's/.0$//' <file>`.

Comment: @Fiximan You should escape the `.` ;-)

Comment: I dont know how to cut it cuz it all look like decimal for ip address. Could you please give a guidance.

Comment: I advise you to provide a less regular input file. In the one you provided, one could simply remove the 18 and 19° characters of each line. But if your lines lengths vary, as they probably do because of the IP addresses, that would be a invalid solution and would waste the answerer's time.

Answer (score 0):

If the decimals on the port are all of a fixed length, you can use the following, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323843)

```
echo ${line%%??}
```

Where the number of `?` corresponds to the fixed number of characters to remove

Alternatively, you can use:

```
echo ${line%.*}
```

From [this bash reference](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22664), the `%` means:

> Strip shortest match of $substring from back of $string

I know it says "shortest," but even when using an IP with small octets and a longer port decimal like 1.1.1.1,42056.0000 I didn't have issues.

To iterate through your file, you can use the following (courtesy of the [first search result](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-bash/) in DuckDuckGo)

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done < input_file
```

Using the above and adding your results to a new file, one way would look like

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo ${line%.*} >> trimmed_file; done < input_file
```

Comment: Of course, if other tools are usable, I would 100% recommend sed. My best sed guess would be `sed -i 's:\.[0-9]\{1,\}::4'` which translates to "remove the fourth occurrence of a period followed by at least one number between 0 and 9." References: [regular expressions](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#toc-uh-8) and [sed](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1)